# Website File and Folder Structure

Tags: php, html, css, structure, directory

I am having a problem learning how proper website structure should be. And by that I mean how to code the pages and how folder structure should be.

Currently I am navigating around my website using GET variables in PHP when you want go to another page, so I am always loading the index.php file. And I would load the page I wanted like so:

```
$page = "error";

if(isset($_GET["page"]) AND file_exists("pages/".$_GET["page"].".php")) {

    $page = $_GET["page"];

} elseif(!isset($_GET["page"])) {

    $page = "home";

}
```

And this:

```
<div id="page">
    <?php
         include("pages/".$page.".php");
    ?>
</div>
```

The reason I am doing this is because it makes making new pages a lot easier as I don't have to link style sheets and javascript in every file like so:

```
<head>
    <title>
        Website Name
    </title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png"/>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

There is a lot of problems doing it this way as URLs don't look normal ("?page=apanel/app") if I am trying to access a page from inside a folder inside the pages folder to prevent clutter.

Obviously this is not the only way to go about it and I can't find the proper way to do it because I'm sure websites don't link style sheets in every file as that would be very bad if you changed a file name or needed to add another file you would have to change it in every file.

If anyone could tell me how it is actually done or point me towards a tutorial that would be great.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: For proper URLs look at mod_rewrite. this can transform pretty urls like /my/page/something.html to /index.php with get vars.

Comment: for example: http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/

Comment: Just FYI, using unsanitized user data from `$_GET` like that opens you up to [path traversal attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack). Path traversal attacks are an extremely common type of attack, all sites should make an effort to protect themselves from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good starting point for you, you could look into how MVCs (Model/View/Controller) like Zend/CodeIgnitor/CakePHP/Symphony etc handle views and templates (I don't really have much experience with these so I can't say how they do it).

Regarding URL's you can use Apache's `RewriteRule` to clean them up, so you could redirect `www.yoursite.com/abc` to `www.yoursite.com/index.php?page=abc`, and your example about folders you could have a URL `www.yoursite.com/somefolder/somepage` redirect to `www.yoursite.com/index.php?page=somefolder/somepage`, or `www.yoursite.com/index.php?page=somepage&folder=somefolder`.

Where I work we use a custom MVC, in which we have a global header and footer file, containing all CSS/JS file links, and any HTML that will be on every page, and then we include separate files for individual pages, but rather that including PHP file, we include [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) files to template our HTML.